# Passing value attribute to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a txt file, which I need to upload to the webpage and process further. My solution was to have a `hidden` tag in the view and get it's value in the controller. I did an upload using `javascript`, which works as expected and I have a value assigned to tag after running script:

```
<input id="filecontents" name="configurationstring" type="hidden" value="{
    "ID": 0,
    "Updated": "\/Date(1524153092965)\/",
    "Countries": [11, 12, 15, 16, 23, 33, 38, 42, 43, 48, 49, 52, 57, 59, 62, 63, 66, 68, 69, 70, 73, 79, 80, 86, 87, 88, 90, 95, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109, 113, 115, 116]
}">
```

And then I have and `ActionLink`, which calls this method from controller:

```
public ActionResult getConfig(string configurationstring)
{
   //perform computations
   return View()
}
```

But, somehow, on the controller side the `configurationstring` is always `null`. Can someone suggest what's the error?

Comment: How are you generating the link and passing a value for `configurationstring`?

Comment: You would also need to escape the `"` marks in the HTML, and I'm not sure if splitting an attribute over multiple lines is even possible.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am just calling `ActionLink("Read","getConfig")`. I thought that `configurationstring` value is automatically identified using `name` attribute. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DavidG, is it really needed? I mean escaping `"` marks, as from source of generated HTML I don't see any failure.

Comment: No its not (an input is only sent to the controller when you post a form)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, oh, then I am back again to the issue with several submit buttons in the form, which makes things rather difficult

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<form action="home/Index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

C#:

```
public class ConfigFile
{
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<int> Countries { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     if (file.ContentLength > 0)
     {
         string inputString = (new StreamReader(file.InputStream)).ReadToEnd();

         JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         var configFile = jss.Deserialize<ConfigFile>(inputString);
     }

     return View();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I know how perform serialization. The issue is that I have already a submit button on the form and putting the second one makes things not right.

Answer (score 0):

if jQuery if feasible, you can do something like this.

write an onclick function and send the stringyfied JSON as a query parameter

```
$("#actionLinkId").on("click",function(e){

e.preventDefault();

window.location.href=url+"?configurationstring="+JSON.stringify($("#filecontents").val())

})
```

might not be the best solution , but it'll work